# using cursor how can i display this on dbms_output.put_line?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
select distinct tbl2.id, tbl1.year
from table1 tbl1 join table2 tbl2
on(tbl1.tbl2id = tbl2.id)
```

here's the output of this query

```
ID     YEAR    
1      2001   
1      2002    
2      1995   
2      1996
```

but the output that I want is something like this

```
1 - 2001, 2002     
2 - 1995, 1996
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using cursors and PLSQL, you can use a [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466):

```
select id || ' - ' || listagg(year, ', ') within group (order by year)
from (
        yourQuery
      )
group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as below. First you can use `LISTAGG` to get the data in a format separated by `comma` and then run a loop;

```
Declare

Cursor xyz is 
          select  tbl2.id,listagg(tbl1.year,',') within group (ORDER BY tbl1.id) 
         from table1 tbl1 
          join table2 tbl2
         on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
         group by tbl2.id 
         order by 1 ;

var1 number;    
var2 varchar2(100);

begin

 Open xyz;
 Loop
  fetch xyz into var1, var2;

  EXIT WHEN XYZ%NOTFOUND;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID-'|| var1 || 'YEAR-' ||var2);

  END Loop;

  close xyz;
End;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/92da8/3)